# Why does size of map changes on comparison?

Tags: c++

Using the below `C++` code prints different sizes of map before and after comparison.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1 = "abc", str2 = "def";
    map<char, int> mp;
    for(char c: str1) mp[c]++;
    cout << "Size of map: " << mp.size() << endl;
    for(char ch: str2) {
        if(mp[ch]) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
    cout << "Size of map: " << mp.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does checking whether a `key` exists in a `map` increases the size of the `map`?

Comment: If you isolated your comparison into a function that takes a map by `const&`, you'd get a [compilation error](https://godbolt.org/z/c63jdj) instead of a silent bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(mp[ch])
```

This will call the `map::operator[]` with key `ch`.

If key matches to an element in `map` it will return the value of that element.
If key does not match to any element in the map, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value.

You can use `map::find` to check if the key is present or not in the map.

Comment: The "function" you're referring to is the index operator, or `operator[]` if you want to add that to the answer.

Comment: Much better, thanks.